# Find and replace value in Swift array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

**How does one search an array of dictionaries for a match and replace that match with another dictionary?**

Where `lineItemsArray:Array` is an array of dictionaries, I am looking to search the array elements for a match, return the index of that match, and then replace the dictionary at that index with a new one. Each dictionary in the array contains a `recordId` key which will be used for the search. Each recordId is unique and the search will always return a single result.

The new data that will be replacing the matching record is generated by web service and returned as a dictionary. (see below)

**Here are my specific questions:**

- How can the array of dictionaries be searched for match?
- How can the index path of that match be returned?
- What is the most efficient manner of replacing the dictionary at the matching index?

This is a sample of what the `lineItemsArray` looks like:

```
[{
    buyFromCompanyId = 1;
    buyFromJobId = 5276;
    comment = "";
    componentId = 2331;
    description = "";
    fulfillmentStatus = 0;
    globalJobId = 2470;
    inventoryItemId = 1824;
    isSerialized = 1;
    itemClass = 0;
    itemQty = 2;
    lineItemId = 50853;
    priceRecordId = 152693;
    productName = "Bose L1 Compact";
    qtyAlreadyPulled = 0;
    qtyRate1 = 3;
    qtyRate2 = "";
    qtyTotalStock = "";
    rate1 = "";
    rate2 = "";
    sellToCompanyId = 1;
}, {
    buyFromCompanyId = 1;
    buyFromJobId = 5276;
    comment = "";
    componentId = "";
    description = "";
    fulfillmentStatus = 0;
    globalJobId = 2470;
    inventoryItemId = 2010;
    isSerialized = "";
    itemClass = "";
    itemQty = 2;
    lineItemId = 50854;
    priceRecordId = 152695;
    productName = "C13 IEC Cable (Standard)";
    qtyAlreadyPulled = 0;
    qtyRate1 = "";
    qtyRate2 = "";
    qtyTotalStock = 23;

}, {
    buyFromCompanyId = 1;
    buyFromJobId = 5276;
    comment = "";
    componentId = "";
    description = "";
    fulfillmentStatus = 0;
    globalJobId = 2470;
    inventoryItemId = 2046;
    isSerialized = 1;
    itemClass = "";
    itemQty = 2;
    lineItemId = 50855;
    priceRecordId = 152697;
    productName = "L1 compact amp unit";
    qtyAlreadyPulled = 0;
    qtyRate1 = "";
    qtyRate2 = "";
    qtyTotalStock = 1;
}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, Swift's global `find` method looks for a specific value instead of a value matching a predicate. You can define your own this way:

```
func find<C: CollectionType>(collection: C, predicate: (C.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> C.Index? {
    for index in collection.startIndex ..< collection.endIndex {
        if predicate(collection[index]) {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then you can find the index of the dictionary in question and replace it directly:

```
let index = find(lineItemsArray) { $0["recordId"] == replaceKey }
if let index = index {
    lineItemsArray[index] = newDictionary
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I did have to more clearly define the array like so: <Int<String, String>>

Comment: Please update answer for Swift 4. I am getting "Generic parameter 'Bound' could not be inferred" in for loop condition

Answer (score 2):

You could use the map method:

```
let newItems = map(lineItems, { originalDict in
    if originalDict["recordId"] == replaceId {
         return newDict
    }
    else {
        return originalDict
    }
})
```

Or as a shorter version:

```
let newItems = map(lineItems) { $0["recordId"] == replaceId ? newDictionary : $0 }
```

map allows you to convert one array into another. Here I am using it to map the original array into a new array where only elements with the matching ID are replaced with a new dictionary.

To do that, I am passing a closure to the map function that checks if the given element has id that should be replaced. I then use the ternary operator to either return the newDictionary or the original dictionary ($0).

I an using two imaginary variables:

- **newDict**: the dictionary you want to replace the old one with
- **replaceId**: the id of the dictionary you want to replace

Note that this creates a copy of the original array with the updates instead of updating the existing array.

Comment: In swift 2.0 its changed ->

let newItems = lineItems.map() { $0["recordId"] == replaceId ? newDictionary : $0 }